# Bootstrap columns do not add to 12

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I'm new to the bootstrap.

I studied the tutorials in w3Schools and my understanding is bootstrap uses a 12 column based grid system.

In my company, I see some codes which never seem to follows that rule.

Example:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="LastNameTextBox" CssClass="col-md-3 control-label">*Last Name:</asp:Label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="LastNameTextBox" MaxLength="50" Width="500" CssClass="form-control" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="LastNameTextBox"
            CssClass="text-danger" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The last name field is required." />
    </div>
</div>
```

As you see, only 11 columns are used and they seem to work properly( I don't see any layout problem if I resize).

What is the problem with the 11 columns used if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap will just give the remaining space to your last style. Your last style will have 9 in instead of 8. I could become a problem if you need your web app to fit on different screen sizes. Probably good practice to define your columns to match 12.